# Merging DFMs with quanteda in R

Tags: r, merge, quanteda, dfm

Im quite new to quanteda and R. Is theyr any chance to merge multiple DFMs rowwise?

I do have at least 3 dfms with multiple texts in them and want to merge them into one dfm.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rbind` to combine them together.

Small example:

```
library(quanteda)

dfm1 <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
  corpus_subset(Year > 1990) %>%
  tokens() %>% 
  dfm()


dfm2 <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
  corpus_subset(Year <= 1990 & Year > 1980) %>%
  tokens() %>% 
  dfm()


dfm_combined <- rbind(dfm1, dfm2)
```

If needed you can run `dfm_compress` afterwards if you notice that there are features or documents that occur in both dfms. Check the help with `?dfm_combined`.